# Alguien sabe por que el keyCode cuando presiono una tecla del evento keypress es diferente al keycode de los eventos keyup y keydown

Tags: javascript

Alguien sabe por que el keyCode cuando presiono una tecla del evento keypress es diferente al keycode de los eventos keyup y keydown[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

No a lo que me refiero es que cuando capturo alguno de esos eventos, la consola me devuelve informacion del evento, en esa info que me devuelve hay una propiedad llamada keyCode que es un numero y es para identificar cada tecla, resulta que cuando capturo los eventos keyup y keydawn me devuelve cada evento un numero que identifica la tecla, por ejemplo si presiono "J" su keyCode es 72 en esos dos eventos, pero con keypress no es así, cuando presiono la misma tecla su keyCode es 106 si no estoy mal, y eso es lo que quiero saber, por que sucede eso, por que el keyCode de las teclas no es el mismo con keypress que con los otros dos eventos.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/356637/169867

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!